# Would the introduction of a keyword "singleton_class" break Ruby code or cause other difficulties?

Tags: ruby

Suppose one wished to create a class having a class instance variable, a getter for that variable, a class method and an instance method. One might write the following.

```
class C
  @v = 1

  def hi
    'hi'
  end

  class << self
    attr_reader :v

    def ho
      'ho'
    end
  end
end

C.methods(false)
  #=> [:v, :ho]
C.ho
  #=> "ho" 
C.v
  #=> 1
```

This could be written many other ways, of course. For example:

```
class C
  @v = 1

  def hi
    'hi'
  end

  def self.ho
    'ho'
  end

  singleton_class.class_eval do
    attr_reader :v
  end
end

C.methods(false)
  #=> [:v, :ho]
C.ho
  #=> "ho" 
C.v
  #=> 1
```

In both cases, `class << self` and `singleton_class.class_eval` cause `self` to change from `C` to `C.singleton_class`. Suppose there were a keyword `singleton_class` that did the same thing, allowing us to write the following.

```
class C
  @v = 1

  def hi
    'hi'
  end

  singleton_class 

  attr_reader :v

  def ho
    'ho'
  end
end

C.methods(false)
  #=> [:v, :ho]
C.ho
  #=> "ho" 
C.v
  #=> 1
```

One could have another keyword that would permit `self` to flip back and forth between `C` and its singleton class, but it might be simplest to require everything after `singleton_class` to be related to the singleton class.

It would not seem that conflicts would arise between the use of the keyword `singleton_class` and local variables or methods of the same name. Consider, for example, the use of the keyword `private`:  (After writing the following I learned that my long-standing belief that `private` is a keyword was incorrect; it is the method [Module#private](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Module.html#method-i-private) used without an argument. I am leaving this here as it is referenced in the comments.)

```
class C
  def m
    private = 'hi'
    private
  end
  private :m

  private
  def private
    'ho'
  end
end
c = C.new
c.m
  #=> NoMethodError (private method `m' called...
c.send :m
  #=> "hi"
c.private
  #=> NoMethodError (private method `private' called...
c.send :private
  #=> "ho"
```

My question is given in the title. Feel free to also offer an opinion as to whether Ruby would benefit from the introduction of a keyword to be used in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Introducing a new keyword *always* breaks existing code.

Before, whatever you introduce was a valid identifier, now it is not.

That is why keywords are very "expensive" and should be used very sparingly. (Ruby already has way too many of them, IMO).

Comment: I'm not suggesting doing away with anything, simply that it would be built into the language to offer another option. Can you give an example of it breaking existing code?

Comment: Every single piece of code that defines a method or constant named `SingletonClass` will be broken, because before the introduction of the keyword, that was a valid identifier, and now it is not. Such is the nature of keywords. You cannot introduce keywords without breaking code. That is the *definition* of "keyword": a word that is otherwise illegal in the language to have a fallback production for the parser.

Comment: Please see my edit concerning the use of local variables and methods named `private`. Can you construct code concerning `private` in which there is a conflict with the use of `private` as a keyword? (I forgot that keywords begin with a lower-case letter, so I've corrected that.)

Comment: I am too lazy now to modify my Ruby installation to have a keyword named `private`, sorry. That test would require to add a new production to the grammar, re-create the parser, re-compile Ruby, which is a little bit more work than I'm willing to spend on an SO answer. I can, however, tell you what the result of that would be: if you add a keyword named `private` to Ruby, then you will no longer be able to define methods or local variables by that name. And you will shadow the current definition of the `Module#private` method in the core library.

Comment: I was under the misapprehension that `private` (and `public` and `protected`}, when used without an argument, was a keyword (rather than the method). Aside from.that I now understand your argument. Thank you for the enlightenment. (I also misstated that [keywords](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/keywords_rdoc.html) always begin with lowercase letters.)